# snmpwalk shows no response but another SNMP client & Wireshark works fine

Tags: snmp

I am **not getting SNMP traps using snmpwalk.** However another SNMP client ("ManageEngine") on the same Windows PC,  easily gets all the traps.  Also the Wireshark shows that the traps are arriving quite fine.

Please guide me, am I doing something wrong?.

the command:

```
snmpwalk.exe -v 2c -c public -t 10 IP:Port
```

**Timeout: No Response from IP:Port**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`snmpwalk` is not suppose to receive any traps by design. It is used to traverse the MIB tree using `GET-NEXT`, `GET-BULK` requests.

Instead you should be using `snmptrapd` to receive traps.

Comment: Thank you, as I tried with snmptrapd, found lots of stuff on screen!!.

Answer (score 3):

You are able to receive trap because your manager on local machine is listening to traps send by remote machine , at port 162.

This does not mean snmpwalk will work. Because in that you are client and sending snmp query to remote host at port 161.

Reason for not responding May be access control list at remote end. 
Wrong community string..
Please check at very first that your server is actively listening for query

Check can be done by nmap for listening

Nmap -sU ip -p 161

Comment: Thanks for the comments. As Mr.Andrew pointed out, the usage of snmptrapd showed me the traps/info. I was using snmpwalk with port162, didnot gave any result.Community string is public, and I dont think ACL issue as the snmp traps are being received by other s/w and wireshark. Nmap